# Simulate a mouse click on a menu item in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts

For example, I have an `NSMenuItem` type variable whose title is "History". I need a keyboard shortcut <kbd>Meta+h</kbd> to do the same thing as to click this menu item (pop up a submenu list)..

I think there might be two ways to implement this:

1.bind this menu item to a keyboard shortcut, then the Cocoa will fire the execute the action belongs to the item when the shortcut is fired

2.not binding keyboard shortcut to the item. Create an EventHandler for <kbd>Meta+h</kbd>, when the event activated, simulate a mouse click on the menu item.

However, both methods don't work for now.

For the keyboard shortcut, there is a method called `setKeyEquivalent`, but it uses <kbd>Command</kbd> instead of <kbd>Meta</kbd> as the modifier. And its result is executing the action binds to the menu item, instead of poping up a submenu.

For the simulating of mouse click, in Cocoa's `NSMenuItem` reference, I haven't see how to send event like `click` to a `NSMenuItem`..

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: You really don't want to simulate mouse clicks with menus unless your building accessibility or automation tools. It requires fiddling with runloops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[menuItem setKeyEquivalent:@" "];  
[menuItem setKeyEquivalentModifierMask:0];
```

with any of these modifier key masks (combined using the C bitwise OR operator):

- NSShiftKeyMask
- NSAlternateKeyMask
- NSCommandKeyMask
- NSControlKeyMask

*(BTW, [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMenuItem/setKeyEquivalent:) can be really useful!)*

Comment: Can be useful but also infuriating. Good luck finding the string for possible keys.

Comment: @uchuugaka The documentation's not always great - true. Getting better all the time, though.. However, the masks are all described right there in the `setKeyEquivalentModifierMask:` doc, same for `keyEquivalent:` including backspace and delete. As for more exotic keys - you might not want to use them at all as your users won't find the keys anyway ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is slightly unclear -

If you set a shortcut Cocoa will invoke the command for you and your code will never know whether the user used the mouse or hit the key equivalent.

If you'd like to invoke the same command by some other means (key in an `NSView`, etc). you'd want to manually call the same method that's hooked up to your menu definition.